# Determining which category has the highest proportion at a chosen significance level

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

From what I understand I can use the chi square to test if there is significant differences between two or more categories of data. But how do I approach it if I want to test that the group with highest is higher than all other groups at a certain significance level?

Comment: Re your title: "which category" is really an estimation problem rather than a testing problem. The body of your question puts it better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare one group to the other groups, you can create a set of binary variabes. In the code below, we assume that category 4 is the one with the highest proportions that you want to compare to the rest:

```
Category    Dummy1vs4   Dummy2vs4  Dummy3vs4
1           0           -           -
2           -           0           -
3           -           -           0
4           1           1           1
1           0           -           -
3           -           -           0
4           1           1           1
4           1           1           1
4           1           1           1
3           -           -           0
2           -           0           -
```

And now you can just run a chi squared test or Fishers test on all of the dummy variables to test if the proportion of category 4 is higher than the others.